# Compute the following expectation with non-independant random variables.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value, independence

Let $X_1$, $X_2$ and $X_3$ be three independant random variables valued in $\mathbb{R}$ on a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ with the same density function $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R})^+$.

We then denote $Y_1=X_1+X_2$, $\ Y_2=X_1+X_3$ and $Y_3=X_2+X_3$. These three random variables have the same density

$$g(x)=\int_\mathbb{R} f(y)f(x-y) \ \mathrm{d}y$$
but **however they are not independant**.

I'm trying to compute the quantity

$$\mathbb{E} \left[\max(Y_1,Y_2) \mathcal{1}_{\{Y_1 \geq Y_3\}} \mathcal{1}_{\{Y_2 \geq Y_3\}} \right] $$
however I'm unable to use a transfer theorem since $Y_1$, $Y_2$ and $Y_3$ doesn't form a family of independant random variables. If they were, I could write something like :

$$\mathbb{E} \left[\max(Y_1,Y_2) \mathcal{1}_{\{Y_1 \geq Y_3\}} \mathcal{1}_{\{Y_2 \geq Y_3\}} \right] = \int_{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \atop x \leq z  \text{ and } y \leq z  } g(x) g(y) g(z) \max(x,y) \ \mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d}y \mathrm{d}z$$
but it's not possible to write that in that case. Is there a way to deal with such expectation involving non-independant random variables ?

All ideas or advices are welcomed.